# Cannot recover grub on Windows 10 / Kubuntu 17.04 Dual Boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, kubuntu, grub-efi

Recently got a laptop with Windows 10, I went ahead and installed Kubuntu 17.04 properly. Never used Windows since and today I made the mistake of using it. Before shutting down it installed updates which removed traces of the grub. I have not been able to boot into grub since.

I went ahead and shut off the Windows 10 hibernate feature here: 
[Installation fails on Grub (Read only EFI partition?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/778117/installation-fails-on-grub-read-only-efi-partition)

I also turned off the Windows 10 fast start feature.

I cannot use the internet on the live CD because it needs a kernel update, there's no ethernet port, and the dongle has only one USB port available for the Live Disk.

I've booted up a live disk with 17.04 for 64 bit systems and have done the following.

Disk layout 
From the output of -fdisk -l i know the following:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1 - efi (100mb) 
/dev/nvme0n1p5 - 23.3 gb kubuntu install
/dev/nvme0n1p6 - home (100gb)
```

I tried the following procedure several times:

```
sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p5 /mnt
sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt/boot/efi
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
sudo chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/nvme0n1 (is this the right location?) 
update-grub
```

There are input/output errors appearing when updating grub, but at the end it says the boot configuration file was updated. After doing a --recheck,it still shows no errors.

I have also done the steps for the thread below on different attempts: 
[How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

After doing these steps I exit chroot and sudo reboot. However I am always brought back to Windows.

Is there something I'm doing wrong, and is there anyway I can boot into grub?

Sincere thanks.

**UPDATE:** Report from Boot-Repair-Disk Iso: http://paste.ubuntu.com/26323545/

Comment: Wndows  probably changed the EFI boot order. OPen the firmware settings by pushing the right key while booting and sellect Ubuntu as the boot OS.

Comment: thanks for your comment - the laptop im using is the Matebook X. its boot order can be brought up using f12 - however, only the Windows Bootloader appears as an option (and the live disk when it is plugged in). i have now tried pushing the right key while booting and it does not do anything on this laptop.

Comment: May be best to see details, you can run from your Ubuntu live installer or any working install, use ppa version not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/  If no networking to boot live installer, save file and then copy  to pastebin site after rebooting into a working system.

Comment: Hi - can't install new programs using ppa since there's no internet on the live disk. i do have the newest boot-repair ISO, maybe it can work? it connected to the internet - http://paste.ubuntu.com/26323545/